# How to turn on debug logging with simctl launch

Tags: ios-simulator, simctl

I want to run my unit tests in several languages:

```
xcrun simctl launch booted com.company.appname -AppleLanguages "(en-GB)"
```

Seems to be the way to run an app in a specific language.

Now, when I run my app from titanium command line in the simulator...

```
ti build
```

...it gives me the debug output (which also holds the results from the unit tests)

How can I get this output using simctl?

(Or should I use another way to run my app in a different language?)

Edit:

running xcode 6.3.2 on Yosemite

Comment: Found a workaraound by creating several instances of the simulator with their own settings like language and locale. We can now select the appropriate simulator and feed it into the ti build command using --device-id:  

ti build --no-colors --no-progress-bars --no-prompt build --platform iphone --log-level info --sdk 3.5.0.GA --project-dir /Users/User/Project/app --target simulator --device-id 100FA320-AC35-4B2A-8530-81E6715FC079

Comment: Have you found a way to launch .app from command line and connected to debugger in Xcode? I need to do this for some reason but can't figure out how.